# How do I determine the GCC version in /proc/version on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gcc, version

my core problem is that I can't find what version of GCC was used to compile my kernel on an Ubuntu machine. I've tried `cat /proc/version`, but the result is the following:

`Linux version 5.19.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-025) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2`

and I'm not certain which number refers to the GCC version. I've included some background below for why I'm doing this in case it turns out to be an XY problem. Thanks.

### **Background:**

I've got an Ubuntu machine sitting in my house (without a monitor connected but with a HDMI dongle that emulates a monitor to make sure it's fast over RealVNC), and it keeps crashing (goes down to remote access, have to physically power cycle). I checked `/var/syslog` and I believe it's a problem with the noveau driver, so I thought I'd install the official Nvidia driver. The problem is that this machine is running with a Geforce GT320, and the current drivers don't support that card. I decided to use the Nvidia Legacy drivers provided by MeowIce, but when I try to install the driver I get an error saying that it can't find the GCC version used to compile my kernel from `/proc/version`. The window says that I could skip that error, but only to do so if I know what I'm doing (which you may be able to tell I don't really).

Comment: It is right there `(x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38)`. Your kernel has been compiled with **gcc-11.3.0**.

Comment: @memchr Thank you so much, I thought that was part of the Ubuntu version.